# Python calendar date missing a whitespace

Tags: python, list, calendar, whitespace

I came across this program and got a part of it fixed here, but I ran into another problem. When it prints out the months, the days are not in the correct position, it's missing a whitespace. I need to get the dates with single digit numbers to be under the last letter of the week. For example number 1 under the "r" letter instead of the "F" letter. Thank you for your help.

[image]

```
calendar1 = [('January', range(1, 31 + 1)),
            ('Feburary', range(1, 28 + 1)),
            ('March', range(1, 31 + 1)),
            ('April', range(1, 30 + 1)),
            ('May', range(1, 31 + 1)),
            ('June', range(1, 30 + 1)),
            ('July', range(1, 31 + 1)),
            ('August', range(1, 31 + 1)),
            ('September', range(1, 30 + 1)),
            ('October', range(1, 31 + 1)),
            ('November', range(1, 30 + 1)),
            ('December', range(1, 31 + 1))]

week = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su']

def make_calendar(year, start_day):

    # Determine current starting position on calendar
    start_pos = week.index(start_day)

    for month, days in calendar1:
        # Print month title
        print('{0} {1}'.format(month, year).center(20, ' '))
        # Print Day headings
        print(' '.join(['{0:<2}'.format(w) for w in week]))
        # Add spacing for non-zero starting position
        print('{0:<3}'.format('')*start_pos, end='')

        for day in days:
            # Print day
            print('{0:<3}'.format(day), end='')
            start_pos += 1
            if start_pos == 7:
                # If start_pos == 7 (Sunday) start new line
                print()
                start_pos = 0 # Reset counter
        print('\n')

yr=int(input('Enter Year'))
strtday=input('Enter start day of the year Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su')
make_calendar(yr,strtday)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
    print('{0:<3}'.format(day), end='')
```

to this:

```
    print('{0:>2} '.format(day), end='')
```

Note that there is a space after the closing brace in the format string.

Your original code says "print `day` left-aligned in a 3-character field".  The new code says "print `day` right-aligned in a 2-character field and then print a space".

Comment: The calendar got messed up totally after I did that change :(

Comment: Then you didn't make the change correctly.  What does that part of your program look like now?